# GENRE through the Spotify iOS SDK

Tags: spotify

Does anyone know whether Genre can be obtained through the Spotify iOS SDK?

It doesn't seem to be listed in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

According to [feature request #31](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/31) dated Apr 20, 2015 on spotify web API on GitHub

> Spotify doesn't expose genres for tracks, the closest you can get is
>   to check the genre of the album the track is on. Genre is however only
>   part of the full album object, and not the simple album object. To get
>   the album's genre, first requesting the [Track metadata](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-track/) to get the
>   album URI, and continue to request [Album metadata](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-album/). You can also
>   get an artist's genres by calling the [Artist metadata](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-artist/) endpoint.